# Unable to set role for user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, .net-core

I'm currently working on .NET Core, and I am trying to assign/authenticate a role for users. For example, an admin named `Robert`  logs into the system, a role called `admin` would be assigned to him. I tried using `ClaimsPrincipal` to do this, but it does not work for me. May I have some advice?

Here are the codes that I have tried:

```
public ActionResult Login (User user)
        {
            if (!AuthenticateUser(user.username, user.password, out ClaimsPrincipal principal))
            {
                //Error Message
            }
            else
            {
                HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                    principal,
                    new AuthenticationProperties
                    {
                        IsPersistent = user.rememberMe
                    });
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

private bool AuthenticateUser(string username, string password, out ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
            principal = null;

            DataTable ds = DatabaseUtil.GetTable(SQL, username, password);
            if (ds.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                principal =
                   new ClaimsPrincipal( 
                      new ClaimsIdentity(
                         new Claim[] {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, username),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, ds.Rows[0][username].ToString()),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, ds.Rows[0][role].ToString())
                         }, "Basic"
                      )
                   );

                return true;

            }
            return false;
        }
```

I even tried using this set of codes to check if the current user is assigned/authentic. But, when I do debug, it shows `Authenticate: False`.

```
System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal currentUser = this.User;
bool IsAdmin = currentUser.IsInRole("admin");
```

Comment: Can you share how you set Identity configuration on startup.cs?

Comment: var claims = new[] {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.madv),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Typ, user.titleid.ToString()),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,user.roleid.ToString())//check  roles
            };

Comment: Link : https://github.com/vankhanhpr/ADHERER/blob/master/source/Adherer/WebApi/serrvice/authentication/responsitoty/AuthenticationResponsitory.cs

Comment: @LuttiCoelho I had this set of codes in my Startup.cs services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddCookie(options =>
                    {
                        options.LoginPath = "/User/Login/";
                        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/Error/";
                    });